# Count and group by in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, aggregate-functions

I have tried many ways but could not be resolved:

```
select count(so.name) as no
from sale_order so 
left join sale_order_line sl on sl.order_id = so.id
group by sl.product_id, so.partner_id
```

Data:

```
SO----------------------order line
1-----------------------11 & 12
2-----------------------21
3-----------------------31
4-----------------------41 & 42
```

I need print count(so.name) = 4

Comment: Your sample data doesn't really match the sample query.  Can you update the question with a better sample of data?

Comment: And some explanation what you are trying to achieve, please.